# @ModelAttribute variable doesn't get a value when redirecting from another controller which adds the attribute to the ModalMap

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model

I have a Spring application and below is a Controller method I have to resolve the `/login`. And I found this code from another application, but I cannot get it to work properly in my application.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(HttpSession session, ModelMap modelMap, Model model,
        @RequestParam("userName") String userName,
        @RequestParam("password") String password, HttpServletRequest req)
        throws IOException, SessionException {

            String page = "home";
            String sessionId = session.getId();
            modelMap.addAttribute("sessionId", sessionId);
            page = "redirect:/home";

            return page;
        }
```

So basically it will redirect to the `/home`

below is the controller to resolve `/home`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(HttpSession session,Locale locale, Model model, @RequestParam(value = "segment", required = false) String segment,
                   @ModelAttribute("sessionId") String sessionId) throws SessionException {

    System.out.println("sessionId : " + sessionId); // this `sessionId` is empty

    return "home";
}
```

But the issue is the `sessionId` is empty when I try to print that. But I can get it from the `HttpSession session`.

What is the reason for this, why the `@ModelAttribute("sessionId") String sessionId` did not get populated with the value though I'm adding it to the ModalMap.

Comment: Because the model is per request and as you are redirecting you get a new request and thus a new model. Either store it as a `RedirectAttribute` or pass it as a URL parameter.

Comment: yeah, seems like that, Thank you. btw I used `<mvc:annotation-driven ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect="true" />`  to avoid model attributes get passed as parameters all the time. I might still need that. As you said I removed this and then above code works fine. How can I keep both , any ideas ?

Comment: @M.Deinum i.e when I change above code snippet in comm.ent into `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` it's working fine

Comment: As stated use `RedirectAttributes` NOT the `Model`. The model isn't passed as it doesn't really exist in a redirect it is rebuild based on the passed in arguments. To circumvent this use `RedirectAttributes` instead. Next to that why do you even need a redirect...